# C++ Int bit manipulating is 2UL = 10UL?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have a quick question.

I've been playing around with bit manipulation in c/c++ for a while and I recently discovered that when I compare 2UL and 10UL to a regular unsigned int they seem to return the same bit.

For example,

```
#define JUMP 2UL
#define FALL 10UL

unsigned int flags = 0UL;
this->flags |= FALL;

//this returns true
this->is(JUMP);

bool Player::is(const unsigned long &isThis)
{
return ((this->flags & isThis) == isThis);
}
```

Please confirm if 2U equals 10U and if so, how would I go around it if I need more than 8(?) flags in a single unsigned integer.

Kind regards,

-Markus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. `10ul` is 1010 in binary and 2 is 10. Therefore, doing `x |= 10` sets the second bit too.

You probably wanted to use `0x10` and `0x2` as your flags. These would work as you expect.

As an aside: a single digit in the hex notation represent 4 bits, not 8.

Comment: Oh, yeah now I get it. Thanks!

Comment: So what I want is 1,2,4,8,16 etc.
What I would do is 1UL, 2^1UL, 2^2UL, 2^3UL.
However it doesn't work as I expected.
Is there a prettier way of defining these values than 512UL, 1024UL, etc?

Comment: @Orujimaru: `1UL << k` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

```
JUMP, 2:  0010
FALL, 10: 1010

FALL & JUMP = JUMP = 0010
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimal 2 in binary is 0010, whereas decimal 10 is binary 1010. If you bitwise-and them `(2 & 10)`, that yields binary 0010, or decimal 2. So `10 & 2` is indeed equal to 2. Maybe your intention is to test for `1ul << 2` and `1ul << 10`, which would be bits number 2 and 10 respectively. Or maybe you meant to use hexadecimal 10, (decimal 16, binary 10000), which is denoted as 0x10.

Comment: Thanks, so 1UL<< 10 isn't equal to 0x10?

Comment: No, not at all. `1u << 0u` is 1 (binary 0000 0000 0001, hex 0x1), `1u << 1u` is 2 (0000 0000 00010, 0x2), `1u << 2u` is 4 (0000 0000 0100, 0x4), and so on. `1u << 10u` is therefore 1024 (0100 0000 0000, 0x400).